# Visual Studio Code failing to download packages

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am running Visual Studio Code 1.16.0 on Windows 10 (Creators Edition). It is failing to download packages:

```
Updating C/C++ dependencies...

Downloading package 'C/C++ language components (Windows)'  Failed. 
Retrying... Failed. Retrying... Failed. Retrying...Waiting 8 seconds... 
Failed. Retrying...Waiting 16 seconds... Failed. Retrying...Waiting 32 
seconds...
Failed at stage: downloadPackages
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 2.22.12.63:443
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1050:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1073:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1097:14)

Finished
```

The PC is connected to the internet via a company proxy server. I can browse the internet from the PC.

What PC setting do I need to change to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by setting VS Code "http.proxy" user setting.